# How to change player speed with public float from another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey I am trying to change a float when my player collides with a object. I tried many ways of reference but only got null when trying to debug I came up with this so far. I want to get the gameobject that contains the player script meaning the player and after I want to get the component script tankmovement to change the variable in it.

Getting the null reference error in the powerups script line 79 reset function `Tank=GameObject.FindWithTag("Player")`

```
        using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    public class PowerUp : MonoBehaviour {

        public bool boosting = false;
        public GameObject effect;
        public AudioSource clip;
        public GameObject Tank;
        private void Start()
        {
           Tank  = GameObject.Find("Tank(Clone)");
          TankMovement script = GetComponent<TankMovement>();
        }

        private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
        {
            if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                if (!boosting)
                {
                    clip.Play();
                    GameObject explosion = Instantiate(effect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
                    Destroy(explosion, 2);
                    GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
                    GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;
                    Tank.GetComponent<TankMovement>().m_Speed = 20f;
                    //TankMovement.m_Speed = 20f;
                    boosting = true;
                    Debug.Log(boosting);
                    StartCoroutine(coolDown());
                }


            }
private IEnumerator coolDown()
    {
        if (boosting == true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
            {
                boosting = false;
                GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
                GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = true;
                Debug.Log(boosting);
               // Destroy(gameObject);

            }
        }
    }

    void reset()
    {
        //TankMovement.m_Speed = 12f;
        TankMovement collidedMovement = Tank.gameObject.GetComponent<TankMovement>();
        collidedMovement.m_Speed = 12f;
        //TankMovement1.m_Speed1 = 12f;
    }

        }
        }
```

Trying to call on my m_Speed float in the player script to boost the speed of my player when he collides with it. How would you get a proper reference since my player is a prefab.

Tank script

```
  using UnityEngine;

    public class TankMovement : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public int m_PlayerNumber = 1;         
        public float m_Speed = 12f;            
        public float m_TurnSpeed = 180f;       
        public AudioSource m_MovementAudio;    
        public AudioClip m_EngineIdling;       
        public AudioClip m_EngineDriving;      
        public float m_PitchRange = 0.2f;


        private string m_MovementAxisName;     
        private string m_TurnAxisName;         
        private Rigidbody m_Rigidbody;         
        private float m_MovementInputValue;    
        private float m_TurnInputValue;        
        private float m_OriginalPitch;         


        private void Awake()
        {
            m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        }


        private void OnEnable ()
        {
            m_Rigidbody.isKinematic = false;
            m_MovementInputValue = 0f;
            m_TurnInputValue = 0f;
        }


        private void OnDisable ()
        {
            m_Rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
        }


        private void Start()
        {
            m_MovementAxisName = "Vertical" + m_PlayerNumber;
            m_TurnAxisName = "Horizontal" + m_PlayerNumber;

            m_OriginalPitch = m_MovementAudio.pitch;
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            // Store the player's input and make sure the audio for the engine is playing.
            m_MovementInputValue = Input.GetAxis(m_MovementAxisName);
            m_TurnInputValue = Input.GetAxis(m_TurnAxisName);

            EngineAudio();
        }


        private void EngineAudio()
        {
            // Play the correct audio clip based on whether or not the tank is moving and what audio is currently playing.

            if (Mathf.Abs(m_MovementInputValue) < 0.1f && Mathf.Abs(m_TurnInputValue) < 0.1f)
            {
                if (m_MovementAudio.clip == m_EngineDriving)

                {
                    m_MovementAudio.clip = m_EngineIdling;
                    m_MovementAudio.pitch = Random.Range(m_OriginalPitch - m_PitchRange, m_OriginalPitch + m_PitchRange);
                    m_MovementAudio.Play();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (m_MovementAudio.clip == m_EngineIdling)

                {
                    m_MovementAudio.clip = m_EngineDriving;
                    m_MovementAudio.pitch = Random.Range(m_OriginalPitch - m_PitchRange, m_OriginalPitch + m_PitchRange);
                    m_MovementAudio.Play();
                }
            }
        }


        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            // Move and turn the tank.
            Move();
            Turn();
        }


        private void Move()
        {
            // Adjust the position of the tank based on the player's input.
            Vector3 movement = transform.forward * m_MovementInputValue * m_Speed * Time.deltaTime;

            m_Rigidbody.MovePosition(m_Rigidbody.position + movement);
        }


        private void Turn()
        {
            // Adjust the rotation of the tank based on the player's input.
            float turn = m_TurnInputValue * m_TurnSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

            Quaternion turnRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, turn, 0);

            m_Rigidbody.MoveRotation(m_Rigidbody.rotation * turnRotation);
        }



    }
```

Comment: It may be an initialization error, can you show us the main() function? The problem happens when you set [...].m_speed = 20f, right?

Comment: I get object refererence not set to instance of object and I dragged my tank prefab onto the gameobject. I want to boost the player speed normal is 12f i want 20f when collides.

Comment: There should two possibilities: Or you are not calling the adequate instance or you didn’t initialize the object. This is why I asked to see the main code, so we can see where did you declare the instance and where were you trying to asign the value.

Comment: I added my scripts but I dont get it should it not be fine how i got the script but still not working as intended only when i change it to static again but that is bad practice i found out

Comment: Ok, then I’m sure it is an initialization problem. You still didn’t post the “main()” function. There, you should first declare Tank t = new Tank();, and then you shall set t.m_speed = 20f;. Understood? tell me if it works and I post an answer!

Comment: @J.Francis There is no `main` function when you are coding for the unity engine.

Comment: @Jerry Does the colliding `GameObject` tagged with `Player` have the `TankMovement` script you are interested in accessing?

Comment: Damn, my bad. I thought it had the same behavior. My apologizes!

Comment: Yes it does @Ruzihm

Comment: I think there's a typo in your question. You never seem to call `FindWithTag` so it's unclear where the exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `TankMovement` component you need to access is attached to the `GameObject` that is colliding with the power, you can get the `TankMovement` component you need to change by using `other.gameObject.GetComponent<TankMovement>()`:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        if (!boosting)
        {
            // stuff
            TankMovement collidedMovement = other.gameObject.GetComponent<TankMovement>();
            collidedMovement.m_Speed = 20f;
            // more stuff
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: If I were to reset the boost in update with a boolean becoming false how would you then reference this I posted what I did in edit and im getting a null reference error

Comment: Please edit your question to show which line you're getting the null reference error on, so I can better understand where the problem is.

Comment: Edited, I am just confused cause my Tank is instantieted which means it spawns in so its not there from the beginning.